Scraping prices from a webpage (VBA macro)
Simply said, I have a big macro which scrapes prices from a number of our customers and their eshops. Now, my macro works on every single one of them with one exception. I have been trying to make it work numerous times, even asked some friends and chatGPT for help, but nothing seems to work.
Normally, the macro is really like 10 lines, including the clean up and everything. In this case, it is getting bloated, there is even a timer, a bunch of suggestions from chatGPT aaaand Im not getting anything from it... Im getting the highlighted response(basically the element I want to download from is not found):
Sub ProcessCaseland(cell As Range)
    ProcessRangeCaseland cell, "<dd class=""even pv-text promokod"">\s*(\d+)\s*&nbsp;Kč\s*</dd>"
End Sub




Sub ProcessRangeCaseland(cell As Range, pricePattern As String)
    Dim url As String
    Dim htmlString As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim extractedPrice As String
    
    ' URL from column C
    url = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    
    ' Debug: Check if URL is being correctly extracted
    Debug.Print "URL from cell " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Address & ": " & url
    
    ' Check if the cell contains a valid URL
    If IsValidURL(url) Then
        ' Introduce a delay to allow the page to fully load
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        
        ' Download HTML content from the URL
        htmlString = DownloadHTML(url)
        
        ' Debug: Print the HTML content to see if it's being downloaded correctly
        Debug.Print "HTML Content from URL: " & vbCrLf & htmlString
        
        ' Create a regular expression object
        Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        With regex
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
            .Pattern = pricePattern
        End With
        
        ' Execute the regular expression match
        If regex.Test(htmlString) Then
            Set matches = regex.Execute(htmlString)
            
            ' Check if we have matches
            If matches.Count > 0 Then
                ' Extract the matched value (price)
                extractedPrice = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
                
                ' Debug: Print the extracted raw price for debugging
                Debug.Print "Raw Extracted Price: " & extractedPrice
                
                ' Clean the extracted price by removing non-numeric characters
                extractedPrice = Replace(extractedPrice, "&nbsp;", "") ' Remove non-breaking space
                extractedPrice = Replace(extractedPrice, " ", "") ' Remove spaces
                extractedPrice = Replace(extractedPrice, "Kč", "") ' Remove currency symbol
                
                ' Output the cleaned, numeric-only price for debugging
                Debug.Print "Cleaned Extracted Price: " & extractedPrice
                
                ' Output the extracted price to the corresponding cell in column D
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ExtractNumbers(extractedPrice)
            Else
                ' no submatches found
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Price not found in regex result"
                Debug.Print "No submatches found in regex result from URL: " & url
            End If
     **   Else
            ' not found in HTML
            cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Price pattern not found in HTML"
            Debug.Print "No price pattern matched in HTML from URL: " & url**
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle case where cell does not contain a valid URL
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Invalid URL"
        Debug.Print "Invalid URL: " & url
    End If
End Sub

Obviously, Im not a pro, Im a beginner and Ive touched VBA for the first time this january or so. But making these scrapers was really easy so far, whenever I made some mistake somewhere, chatgpt saved me (sorry, Im really not a pro)...
Here is the URL : https://www.krytoland.cz/prenosny-monitor-arzopa-s1-table-15-6
If anyone can help, I would be extremely thankful.

Have you checked the value of htmlString? Does it include the information you need?

Yes, everything seems just fine. The issue seems to be that it cannot find the element. Normally a timer would be able to deal with that, or something that would push a button/tick a box etc, but here in this case, I have no idea what to do with it

Does DownloadHTML also execute js of the (interactive) web side? I guess this is necessary to get the needed information.

It looks like the HTML is being rendered by Javascript, as suggested by Shrotter. The good news is that the details that you're after - the price - is still available from within the code, stored in JSON format:
gtag('event', 'view_item', { "currency": 'CZK',"value": 2359,"items": [{"id": "193239135","name": "Přenosný monitor Arzopa S1 TABLE 15,6"","category": "Krytoland pouzdra a kryty na mobil","quantity": 1,"price": '2359'}]})


You can try sending a XMLHTTP request to the server and then parse the server answer to get the price, which is done by the below code;
Sub Test()
    Dim objHTTP As Object, strURL As String
    Dim x1 As Long, x2 As Long, myVal As Variant
 
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    strURL = "https://www.krytoland.cz/prenosny-monitor-arzopa-s1-table-15-6"
 
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.send

    x1 = InStr(1, objHTTP.responseText, """price"":")
    x2 = 150
    
    If x1 > 0 Then
        myVal = Split(Mid(objHTTP.responseText, x1, x2), "'")(1)
    Else
        myVal = "Price not found!"
    End If
    
    MsgBox myVal
End Sub

.
If you want to use Regular Expressions to parse the server answer as in your original code, you can use the below code;
Sub Test2()
    Dim objHTTP As Object, strURL As String
    Dim regExp As Object, matches As Object, extractedPrice As Variant
 
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    strURL = "https://www.krytoland.cz/prenosny-monitor-arzopa-s1-table-15-6"
 
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.send
    
    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    With regExp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = """price"":\s?'(.+?)'"
    End With
    
    If regExp.Test(objHTTP.responseText) Then
        Set matches = regExp.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
        
        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            extractedPrice = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    Else
        extractedPrice = "Price not found!"
    End If
        
    MsgBox extractedPrice
End Sub

